# $\frac{a}{1-a}+\frac{b}{1-b}+\frac{c}{1-c}+\frac{d}{1-d}+\frac{e}{1-e}\ge\frac{5}{4}$

Tags: inequality

I tried to solve this inequality:
$$\frac{a}{1-a}+\frac{b}{1-b}+\frac{c}{1-c}+\frac{d}{1-d}+\frac{e}{1-e}\ge\frac{5}{4}$$
with 
$$a+b+c+d+e=1$$
I am stuck at this. I don't want the full solution, a hint would be enough.

Comment: what is the nature of $a,b,c,d,e?$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Good point, the inequality is false for $a,b,c,d,e \notin (0,1)$.

Comment: @ABlumenthal, I think they are positive real numbers so that each $<1$

Comment: yes, i forgot to say this again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint:**

You have $1-a=b+c+d+e$ and
$a=1-(b+c+d+e)$

$\dfrac{1-(b+c+d+e)}{b+c+d+e}=\dfrac{1}{b+c+d+e}-1$ and $b+c+d+e=1-a$

Using AM $\ge$ HM

$(\dfrac{1}{1-a}+\dfrac{1}{1-b}+\dfrac{1}{1-c}+\dfrac{1}{1-d}+\dfrac{1}{1-e}) \ge \dfrac{5^2}{1+1+1+1+1-(a+b+c+d+e)} $

Comment: I thought about the first hint, but I didn't try to use AM/HM.

Answer (score 5):

HINT:

$$\frac a{1-a}=-1+\frac1{1-a}$$

Assuming  $a,b,c,d,e$ to be positive real numbers, $1-a>0 $

Using AM HM [inequality](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/Root-Mean_Square-Arithmetic_Mean-Geometric_Mean-Harmonic_mean_Inequality) on $1-a$ etc

$$\frac{\sum (1-a)}5\ge \frac5{\sum \frac1{1-a}}\implies \sum \frac1{1-a}\ge\frac{5^2}{5-\sum a}=\frac{25}{5-1}$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: with $g(a,b,c,d,e) = a + b + c + d + e$ and 
$$f(a,b,c,d,e) = \frac{a}{1-a}+\frac{b}{1-b}+\frac{c}{1-c}+\frac{d}{1-d}+\frac{e}{1-e}$$
we can consider optimizing $f$ over the set of $(a,b,c,d,e)$ for which $g(a,b,c,d,e) = 1$. The method of lagrange multipliers gives a necessary condition for the existence of a critical point on this set: $\nabla f = \lambda \nabla g$ for some $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$.

However we know that $\nabla g$ is the column vector $(1,1,1,1,1)$, which means that
$$
\frac{1}{(1-x)^2} = \lambda
$$
for each $x = a,b,c,d,e$ individually. Notice that this condition is the same for each coordinate.

What can you conclude about the solutions to the lagrange multiplier problem, and how can you connect this information to the inequality you wish to prove?

Comment: I assumed in this hint that the optimization problem is carried out in the reals.

Comment: You need to show existence of a minimum to use this technique. Since you cannot acheive minimum if one of the components is close to $1$, you can assume you are working over $[0,1-\varepsilon] \times \dots \times [0,1-\varepsilon]$ (intersected with the constraint). The set is compact, the function is continuous, you have a minimum. It will not be on the boundary if you compute what happens then, hence must happen in the interior on which you have a Lagrange condition which characterizes it.

Answer (score 0):

A proof in one line:
$$\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{a}{1-a}-\frac{1}{4}\right)=\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{(5a-1)}{4(1-a)}-\frac{5}{16}(5a-1)\right)=\sum_{cyc}\frac{(5a-1)^2}{16(1-a)}\geq0.$$
Done!